# Accelaration coding in Unity for vertical game

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I used a code to make my game get faster the longer the game lasted but the problem I faced there was that the actual screen got faster rather than the player and blocks it jumps on and eventually the player would no longer be in the screen.

Is there a way I can accelerate the game over time through the player's gravity scale and platforms public float named "Jump force"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

i think you should take a look at Time.Timescale,
here's the link. this is most likely a easy fix if you're trying to do what i think you're trying to do.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-timeScale.html

you can just increase or decrease this variable according to the actions you're giving as a example.